# In vscode, how to debug on the computing node of a SGE cluster?

Tags: cluster-computing, remote-debugging, remote-server, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I am trying to do some debug with VSCode on the computing node of a SGE cluster via qrsh commands. However, every time I entered the debug mode, it always remained at the login node instead of the computing node.

Here's my dilemma:

First, log in login-node via remote-ssh in vscode

Then apply a compute-node with gpu via qrsh command

Each time the hostname of the compute-node could change.

If I hit the debug button trying to do some debugging on the python programmes, it would go back to the login-node.

I tried to google a solution, some people mentioned that can try with proxy jump in ~/.ssh/config. But it seems not realistic since the applied compute-node's hostname is always different with the previous one.

At the moment, I have to either print everything out or use pdb.set_trace(). Both of them are not convenient for me because some python programmes are very huge. Using the IDE debugging function is really helpful and efficient for understanding other people's coding.

Is there any solution to fix it?

I tried to google some solution, but most of them are for slurm cluster, rather than SGE cluster.

Comment: I've also tried with debugpy. But it still cannot recognise the compute node.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards in `~/.ssh/config` host definitions.

For example, if the compute nodes in your HPC are named `compute-1`, `compute-2`, `compute-3`, etc. then you can set up a single definition for all these hosts.

```
Host compute*
```

You don't give an example of how `ProxyJump` might be used here so I can't test this, but hopefully this gets you one step closer to a solution.